# Using webpack 2 from gulp (webpack-stream for webpack 2)?

Tags: gulp, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to update to webpack 2. I use webpack-stream to run stuff from gulp, but it appears that webpack-stream is using it's own dependency on webpack which is webpack 1.

I have not been able to find any webpack-stream with webpack 2. Is there any possibility to use webpack 2 from gulp?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to have both `webpack` and `webpack-stream` installed:

```
npm install --save-dev webpack-stream
npm install --save-dev webpack@2.1.0-beta.25
```

Then you can pass the `webpack` object as the second parameter to `webpack-stream`:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
var webpack2 = require('webpack');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream({/* options */}, webpack2))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks a lot! Was really simple :) The errors are though in a bit different format

Comment: Do you know maybe how to fix that as well? (I have red errors in separate line directly from node, but only console and a bit messed up new lines in gulp

Comment: No idea, sorry. You might have to wait for a newer version of `webpack-stream`. Maybe file an issue on GitHub?

Comment: It's not a critical thing, so I guess I'll live with it. Thanks a lot for help anyway :)

Comment: Thanks @SvenSchoenung! I was missing that last argument into the webpackStream for using a different version of webpack. I've been stuck on this for hours.

Comment: **Fair warning** webpack-stream has been abandoned for quite some time now and the [fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-stream-fixed), while patching it some, doesn't solve the rest of the open issues on the original repo.

Comment: For your information, there is a new version of webpack-stream for webpack2.  You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack2-stream-watch).