# Gulp webpack-stream run production

Tags: webpack, gulp

I use gulp to run Webpack, with webpack-stream.

I use this [config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575024/2138460) and works will with me.

How can I run Webpack production-build **webpack -p**  from gulp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#the-automatic-way) using `webpack -p` is equivalent to the following:

```
webpack --optimize-minimize --define process.env.NODE_ENV="'production'"
```

Those two options add the [`webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#minification) and the [`webpack.DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production-build/#node-environment-variable) respectively.

What you need to do is to manually add those two plugins in your webpack configuration.

Based on [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40575024/2138460) that you linked to that should look like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
var webpack2 = require('webpack');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  var options = {
    plugins: [
      new webpack2.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': { 'NODE_ENV': "'production'" }
      }),
      new webpack2.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]
  };
  return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream(options, webpack2))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Webpack 4 supports specifying `mode: "production"` in the config object.

Here's the config (shamelessly borrowing from Sven's answer):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
var webpack4 = require('webpack');  // Assuming we've installed Webpack 4+

gulp.task('default', function() {
  var options = {
    mode: "production"
  };
  return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
    .pipe(webpackStream(options, webpack4))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```